# C# - How can i select network kind on ftp transfer

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, networking, ftp

now i developing ftp client application for WinForm(C#)

if windows(OS) connected 2 networks(wireless and Wired-LAN),
i want add this function.
select network(wireless and Wired-LAN) for connect and transfer ftp server.

i have to need 2 connections. 
because when i connect ftp-server, it must be connected to Wired-LAN. and when i do debug on my web-app. it must be connected to wireless(Wi-Fi).
it can't change. it decided on company.
(only wireless network can connect to ftp-server and only Wired-LAN network can connect to debug web-server)

and i don't want do disconnect and re-connect when use ftp client.

Dozens of times a day i upload and download files(web-app and resources) at ftp-server.
and after i disconnect wifi and i did debug my web-app.

so i want it. select network(wireless and Wired-LAN) when connect and transfer ftp server.

do you have any idea? is it possible?

Comment: Your program should not care about which NIC to choose - this is your OS's job (or the routing tables', to be precise).

Comment: When you connect to a FTP server, you specify the IP Address you want to connect to. This Address determine the route. If it's a WAN address, it will take the *Internet* route. If it's a local/intra address, it will take the other route. Of course, your LAN must be configured correctly. See what is the Default Gateway of the two connections. Open up `cmd.exe` and insert `ROUTE PRINT`, see what routes are defined there and add/modify if needed. Modify the `hosts` file if required.